# Do I need a transit visa to travel to ireland via UK?

Tags: uk, transit-visas

I am having an Irish residence permit. I am travelling via UK airport to Dublin. Do I need a transit visa?

Comment: What's your nationality? Do you also have a valid Irish biometric visa?

Comment: The phraseology sounds like the OP is from India. If this is the case, then the British-Irish Visa Scheme will allow them to transit (and indeed visit) the UK without a further visa. However, the visa must be stamped "BIVS", and the scheme isn't available to Pakistani or or Bangladeshi citizens - It is only available to Indian and Chinese citiziens

Comment: One source of confusion might be that Irish residence permit cannot be used to make a layover in UK en route to Ireland, but a short-term biometric visa (BIVS endorsement) can be used.

Comment: thats is true , this is the source of confusion => Irish residence permit cannot be used to make a layover in UK en route to Ireland,